# Redux not registering actions after document.open()

Tags: javascript, events, dom, redux, document.write

I have three sagas listening for the same action, and therefore happening more or less concurrently. One of them rewrites the page using:

```
document.open();
document.write(content);
```

After that happens, the Redux dev tools stops registering new actions (whether from our app, console, or dispatched from the dev tools provided) and we can’t see the subsequent actions happening, even though we know they happened because we can call our code that listens to the action (so it must have dispatched although we can’t see it). We see the expected result of our code on the page.

I thought the issue might be with Redux dev tools only, but we have a custom middleware that collects all events going through the store for analytics purposes - and the expected action is not present in the tracked events either.

The versions I am using:
"redux": "^3.7.2",
"redux-saga": "0.16.0",
"redux-devtools-extension": "2.13.2",

Comment: `document.open()` will clear all existing HTML/javascript, so it can be expected that your redux would just stop working. Why are you using `document.open()`?

Comment: I guess I didn't realise that it would clear the js as well. But then how come the functions that I call afterwards are still working? We are rewriting the document to avoid redirecting the page on our platform - our server response is the full document, including <doctype>

Answer (score 1):

**[document.open()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/open)** allows you to overwrite the current document or append to it.It open a document stream for writing. **If a document exists in the target it clears it**
Also, an automatic `document.open()` call happens when `document.write()` is called after the page has loaded. You should not use `document.write`.
**Solution**
If you want to append something to `<body>` use `document.body.appendChild()`

Comment: The problem is I need to replace the whole page, including the `<head>`, because that's what I get from the server

Comment: @Livia Rett `document.write` it self calls `document.open()` try removing `document.open()`